# error in using doc string example usage as given in book

Tags: python

I am learning python by the examples given in a book here is an example which I typed on terminal

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def square(x):
...     'Calculates the square of the number x'
...      return x*x
```

upon pressing enter above code gives following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    return x*x
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I had typed this on the terminal I am not sure what more needs to be indented, 
basically the example given in the books deals with use of doc strings in python i.e. the strings that explain the functions what they do so if the above would have worked my next step would be to verify if the doc string could be accessed as given in book

```
>>> square.__doc__
'Calculates the square of the number x.'
```

or verifying the use of help function on interactive interpretor

```
>>> help(square)
Help on function square in module __main__:
```

I am practicing this in an interactive interpreter (terminal) , let me know what is the mistake I did above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space just before `return` statement.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out yes it is working now, is there a way I do not need to retype the typed programes on the intepreter once it gives error some kind of copy paste that works?

Comment: @RegisteredUser, I use _Ctrl_ key for highlighting block of code instead of line. Then press wheel button to paste from buffer. Try to do it.

Comment: It's not unusual for typeset books to have issues with fixed spacing, especially around opening quotes (many typesetting scripts replace apostrophes in authors' manuscript files with proper typographers' quotes, and have limited support for preserving "programming quotes" in code displays.) Anyway, there should be the same number of spaces before the doc string and the other code in the function definition.

Comment: actually I am using a laptop I right clicked and highlighted the block of code it is highlighted and along with it ... these three dots which are there after each next line also get copied if I paste it by Ctrl+V then this gives a lot of errors there is no wheel button

Comment: Try using [`ipython`](http://ipython.org) which is a lot more friendly in terms of repeating code and copy-paste.

Comment: @RegisteredUser, actually, I'm talking about this([screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/e8cp988dj/)). You can also see [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/430153/block-select-on-a-linux-console) about block highlighting in linux terminals.